# Spoiler text is not hidden in community digest newsletter

Tags: bug, newsletter, spoilers

I received a SciFi newsletter today and the spoiler tags were not hidden, unlike how they are elsewhere on the site. This seems inconsistent. Can this be fixed?

Image is attached with **spoiler** questions highlighted (do not read if you want to avoid Game of Thrones spoilers):

[Newsletter screenshot with spoilers (warning GoT  season 3 spoilers)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kwwb8.png)

Relevant spoiler questions:

- [Was there any mention of Theon being disfigured this way in the books?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36823/was-there-any-mention-of-theon-being-disfigured-this-way-in-the-books?newsletter=1&nlcode=1205%7C545b)
- [When did the traitor turn?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36841/when-did-the-traitor-turn?newsletter=1&nlcode=1205|545b)

Comment: Newsflash: StackExchange spoils its children.

Comment: This is still happening, as I discovered my linked question, which turned out to be effectively a duplicate of this once I cleared up the misapprehension that I was asking for emails to include hidden text.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the only reasonable way to do this, as perhaps you intended, is to remove the spoiler content entirely from the email.

Otherwise you would have to include them as hidden text in the email, which contains the message twice over, once as plain text and once as HTML. It would not be possible in the plain text and might be hard to do for all clients in HTML.

Removing the spoilers does mean that readers have to visit the question to read them, but that does not seem to be a significant disadvantage.

Answer (score -1):

As a potential alternative, perhaps something simple like ROT13 encoding? It avoids casual reading of the content, but is easily reversible, particularly if we automatically include a link to the encoded/decoded text.