# Please hide (meant: do not reveal) spoilers in emails!

Tags: feature-request, email, spoilers

#### Clarification:

> *This has been misunderstood as asking for spoilers to be included in emails as hidden text; since people have voted on that basis, I formulated a replacement but found [Spoiler text is not hidden in newsletter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184962/spoiler-text-is-not-hidden-in-newsletter), which is what I meant. Please support that if you agree!*

Questions such as [Why Did Narcissa Malfoy Lie About Harry?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10127/why-did-narcissa-malfoy-lie-about-harry#) (on SF & Fantasy) are too often quoted in e-mails with spoilers partially revealed: the newsletter of 2019-04-01 displays the first six words of the spoiler in that question (when previewed or read in Thunderbird).

It seems to me evident that it would be desirable to hide spoilers completely in emails and very likely that it would not be too hard to do. Could you please do this?

If anyone feels that it *is* reasonable to reveal them in emails, I feel the burden of proof is with them: please explain why almost everybody who does not want details revealed on the site should be happy to read them in emails, or why they should be expected to deprive themselves of email notifications if they feel otherwise. If some people are just not bothered, fair enough, but perhaps they can support consideration for others anyway. If it is too hard to be worth doing, I should be interested in an explanation.

Comment: Are you saying that the spoiler text which is normally hidden on the main site is not being hidden in an email?

Comment: @Makoto: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: Interesting.  I hadn't known that.

Comment: @Makoto: I saw that you removed my request for explanations of downvotes (and remarks on possible objections): is it just not done to ask for explanations? If so, I am sorry but also puzzled to have offended: are you able to point me to a place where this is explained?

Comment: Asking why people downvoted is often routinely removed from posts as it's considered irrelevant commentary. Additionally, such requests for explanations can sometimes result in more downvotes.

Comment: Also, note that here on Meta Stack Exchange, on questions requesting new features, voting is used to signify agreement or disagreement with a given proposal, so if your question gets downvoted, it may just mean that people disagree with your proposal, not necessarily that your question is bad for the site.

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog: Thanks for the explanation; I suppose that has the corollary that reputation on meta means something different from what it means in the communities – but still determines one’s privileges!

Comment: See here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143251/if-mse-rep-is-used-for-voting-why-is-it-tied-to-privileges

Comment: On the contrary, I don't think it would be easy or even possible to hide spoilers in email messages with every email client used. Each client can process email differently. Even if several would appropriately hide the text (and I'm not sure what coding could actually accomplish that in most email applications), others wouldn't. It would be better if you asked to simply not email spoilers *at all*.

Comment: Given your recent edit, I've voted to mark this as a duplicate of [Spoiler text is not hidden in newsletter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184962/spoiler-text-is-not-hidden-in-newsletter), the question you linked.

Comment: @JasonBassford: Your comment makes me realise that I formulated my request poorly; as I say in my new edit I just meant “do not reveal spoilers” rather than “include spoilers as hidden text”. And that is already reported as a bug [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184962/spoiler-text-is-not-hidden-in-newsletter).

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog: fine!

Comment: To get attention for that request, you can follow the instructions at [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306398).