# Community Digest newsletters don't respect spoiler tags

Tags: bug, spoilers, community-digests

For example, question [How did Rey find this structure intact?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/225251/how-did-rey-find-this-structure-intact) has a spoiler block near the start:

[image: Question on Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker with functioning spoiler hiding]

But in the community digest that question appeared without the spoiler blocked out:

> [image: Question on Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker with visible spoiler]

It pretty much defeats the purpose of spoiler tags if you've been spoiled before you even get to the page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spoiler text is not hidden in newsletter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184962/282094). Newsletters lack spoilers, and there's a [tag merge / synonymize request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333728/282094) for newsletter to community-digest.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Merging tags may help, but currently if you search for "community digest spoiler" the only question that shows up is mine.  I've edited the title of the other one.

Comment: Randy, At least that bumps it, voting up or adding a bounty in a month or two also could bring more attention to it.